# How to get average rating and number of ratings of a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find the count of ratings and the average value from facebook pages.

I obtained a long term page token via oauth and can access everything but these fields. Am I missing something, or do they not return these like google places or foursquare APIs do ?

I can collect individual ratings via /{page-id}/ratings, however, if I have a page with 1,000 reviews, will all these be returned? Is it a reliable alternative to calculate my own averages/count?

The google places rating count is a hidden field (not shown in the API docs). Hoping there might be one of these for facebook...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get page ratings and review using [**/page/ratings**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/ratings) node . There isn't an aggregate rating attribute for the facebook pages mentioned in the graph api docs .But you calculate the aggregate rating from the individual ratings obtained via graph api .

Graph api is pretty reliable and you should get almost every post via that . and yeah you can calculate your own averages/count cause when dealing with 1,000 reviews even if you miss 1 or 2 it won't make a big difference  as ratings is between (1-5) .

**note :**

It is mentioned here at [**page/feed**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed) that

> All of these derivative edges share the exact same reading structure,
>   however /feed should be used for all publishing purposes. They all
>   have an upper boundary for the limit parameter of 250 posts.
>   Specifying any higher limit will throw an error.

So for obtaining something like 1000 posts , make sure you will be using paging .

Comment: Annoying, but hey ho. Actually, I'll limit it to 250 as it is newest first anyway, so will give a better result for my use. Also, for speed in processing, I discovered adding ?fields=rating to the API call will give a smaller json payload and faster API response.

Comment: @Paul if its just the ratings number you want then its a good approach :) .

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this was the case when this question was asked, but now there's an `overall_star_rating` field on the page.

You can access it like so: `/{page-id}?fields=overall_star_rating`

There's also a rating count, which you can access with : `/{page-id}?fields=rating_count`

Both are listed in their docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: you save my day. this is very helpful. i spent hours searching for this. you are a good person. thank u very much.