# Get Facebook page rating via Page Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a script (in PHP) to collect page ratings' value (i.e. number of stars) of pages **I don't own** (I suspect the issue explained below comes from this).

```
$pageGetURL = str_replace('www.facebook.com','graph.facebook.com', $pageURL); 
// $pageURL is the format https://www.facebook.com/page_name/
$getURLRatings =  $getURLGeneral . 'ratings';
```

so **$getURLRatings** will be in the format https://www.facebook.com/page_name/ratings

According to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/) I should be able to get the rating value (for example of first review) by:

```
json_decode($cUrl_result)->data[0]->rating
```

However 'data' field is **always empty**, including pages of which I know ratings are available.

I'm using cURL to query Facebook Graph API and I'm sure it works because when I call the API at / and /posts it just works.

I tried both with v2.1/ and v2.5/ (latest) API.

I also saw this recent post where apparently it works for them: [How to get average rating and number of ratings of a facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760273/how-to-get-average-rating-and-number-of-ratings-of-a-facebook-page)